# Compressing a list of integers for search access

Tags: c, algorithm, search, compression, inverted-index

I have an prefix-to-rows mapping that looks something like this:

```
{
    "x":   [9],
    "far": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "car": [1,4,5]
}
```

The key is the indexed search term and the array is a sorted list of the rows that have a match. Simple enough, a basic inverted index. And for this question, let's suppose `a-z0-9` characters with a maximum length of three 
characters (upper bound or 36+(36^2)+(36^3)=47,988 combinations, though probably much less in practice, let's say around 10k combinations).

However, the tricky part is that I may have ~ 10M rows, and low-cardinality items could have a (meaningless) list of all 10M rows. In my calculations an 10M-row array itself comes out to 88.9MB uncompressed.

What would be a suggested way to compress these often-repeated arrays? It seems that this must be a very common occurrence in search, and I'd like to learn a bit more about the best method of handling large and repeating prefix maps, such as with the above.

Comment: Can you just special-case the "all rows" case?

Comment: @user202729 I suppose so -- how would that be done? And how would the "all rows" be different than the "no rows"? What if, for example, there was only one row returned vs. all but one rows returned in the search?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_data_structure

Comment: @MattTimmermans -- thanks for that link. In the above case, are there any known algorithms/structures in open-source (C/C++) that I could look into to use in the above case?

Comment: Dunno about C/C++ implementations, but any full text search engine will use something similar for postings lists.  In Java, I'd suggest stealing the one from Elastic Search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using something like Roaring Bitmaps (described in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06549.pdf)). There are implementations in Python, Java, and C, and they automatically switch between 3 different formats for optimal storage density. If you want to implement something similar yourself, it essentially combines:

1. Arrays (the default)
2. Bitsets (good for more dense collections)
3. Run-length encoding (store the start of every "run" of continuous numbers and the length of that run)

The concept works for 32-bit unsigned integers, which comfortably could contain information on 10M rows without any additional work necessary for customizing your own solution.

Comment: thanks for these suggestions, that's certainly a possibility. Two points for that: (1) What about using something like this: https://github.com/lemire/SIMDCompressionAndIntersection (also by the same author as your above paper)? What would be the difference between that and something like RoaringBitmaps? (2) There's a similar blog post about search, https://blog.algolia.com/inside-the-algolia-engine-part-2-the-indexing-challenge-of-instant-search/, and in the comments mentions that Roaring Bitmaps isn't a good fit for their application. Why wouldn't it be? Cheers for the answer!

Comment: (1) I think the short answer is that it would be a good alternative! If you look at the conclusion of http://db.ucsd.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/sidm338-wangA.pdf, referenced in that link, it suggests that roaring makes some tradeoffs but isn't overall better or worse than sorted-list compression methods using SIMD
(2) It seems like they have a different use case? They're updating their index frequently, using ~100 GB of storage, and their data are structured such that the vast majority of their lists are sparse. They don't compress and thus can update the index fast enough to do it live